# Keyboard shortcuts for answers

Tags: feature-request

Many times I find myself having to scroll a lot just to read the next answer for a question, and I'd like to know if there are any hotkeys in place for going through them. And, if that's not the case, wouldn't it be awesome if you could just press <kbd>j</kbd> and skip useless answers?

Following the line of this feature proposal, a like hotkey could be added for <kbd>l</kbd>, a flag one for <kbd>f</kbd>, etc. And, if these exist, shouldn't some kind of information dialog be visible in the site, so that everyone knows about them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This already exist, nearly exactly as you describe. Go to your profile > edit profile and settings > preferences. Enable keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

After that, you can type <kbd>?</kbd> to see a list of options:

[image]

Comment: Well, many thanks. The design is somewhat ugly though...

Comment: @EricBrandwein I agree, but once you get used to them you don't have to have the big black box sitting there all the time.